# Trying to write a Flow formula using a picklist field. Whenever a stage changes in the Opportunity the probability must change with it

Tags: formula, opportunity

Here is the Formula I have created. I am stuck because I keep getting an error stating too many or not enough `(` or Field StageName is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName= "Pre-Qualification"), 0,0,
  IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Qualification'), 10,0,
    IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Ready for Audit'), 10,0,
      IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Ready for Audit'), 10,0,
       IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Audit'), 10,0,
        IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Project Design'), 40,0,
         IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Proposal Review'), 75,0,
          IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Active Negotiation'), 90,0,
           IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed - Won'), 100, 0,0,
            IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Stalled (On-hold)'), 0,0,
             IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Lost'), 0,0,
              IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Qualified Out'), 0,0,
                IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName,''), NULL,0)))))))))))))/
```

Comment: I just deleted the = at the beginning and got the following:  Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IF()` function takes 3 arguments, so you're not chaining them together correctly (you're trying to pass 4 arguments instead of 3).

The typical pattern for chaining `IF()`s together looks like

```java
IF( 
    /* Arg 1: The condition to check */
    My_Checkbox__c,
    /* Arg 2: The value to return if the check results in True */,
    'Is Checked',
    /* Arg 3: The value to return if the check results in False */
    /* If you use another IF() here, then you have an "else if" */
    IF(
        Name = 'Dark Helmet',
        'Spaceballs',
        'Default value if none of the chained conditions are satisfied'
    )
)
```

In your situation though, it would be better to [use the `CASE()` function](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_case.htm&type=5) instead.

e.g.

```java
CASE(
    StageName,
    'Pre-Qualification', 0,
    'Qualification', 10,
    /* and so on... */
    'Qualified Out', 0,
    /* Default value if the StageName doesn't match any of these options */
    0
)
```

`CASE()` is one of the few functions that can work directly with picklists.

Comment: Thank you so much Derek.I do not do this often so this helped a lot!